# Vba runtime error 13 type mismatch on for loop

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I got in stuck with this code. I get back always this error but i have set all the variables and are numbers.

Could you help me?

Here the code

```
Sub calc()
    Dim betexcel As Workbook
    Dim prono As Worksheet
    Dim test As Worksheet

    Set betexcel = Workbooks("BET EXCEL.xlsm")
    Set prono = betexcel.Worksheets("PRONO")
    Set test = betexcel.Worksheets("TEST")

    Dim db As String
    db = prono.Range("A1").Value


    Dim alldata As Workbook
    Dim i1 As Worksheet

    Set alldata = Workbooks(db)
    Set i1 = alldata.Worksheets("I1")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    lastRow = i1.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each Match In test.Range("A6:" & test.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Address)
        MsgBox ("ciao")

        For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1

            If CDate(i1.Range("B" & i).Value) > CDate(Match.Value) Then

                'i1.Rows(i).Delete

            End If

        Next i

 '            Match.Offset(, 1).Select
 '            Selection.Copy
 '            prono.Range("B8").Select
 '            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    Next


End Sub
```

The error is on `If CDate(i1.Range("B" & i).Value) > CDate(Match.Value) Then`

Comment: Hard to spot `exact` issue, but a few notes which will help regardless. **1)** `Match` - change this variable name and also define the new variable as a range. `Match` is a built-in worksheet function. It's a bad idea to use variables names that are already in use by Excel. **2)** Use `Option Explicit` at the top of modules. It will save you many headaches. **3)** Dimension `i` and `LastRow` as Long. Your code will fail for datasets longer than ~32,768 rows.

Comment: Is it **definitely** the `For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1` being highlighted when the error occurs, or was that the last line that successfully ran (perhaps while you were stepping through the code) and the highlighted statement is actually the `If CDate(i1.Range("B" & i).Value) > CDate(Match.Value) Then` line?  (That one may have reasons for a type mismatch, but I can't see a reason for `For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1` causing a problem.)

Comment: Have you tried using any `Debug.Print [VARIABLE NAMES]` anywhere? Or trying `step by step` to find where the issue is occurring? These options might be able to help

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I just saw the comment you left on the (now deleted) answer, saying that the error line was the `If CDate(...` line.

Comment: When the code crashes, what is the value of `i`?  And what is the value of `Match.Value`? And what is in column B of row `i` in your "I1" worksheet?